# the result of ElasticSearch aggregation Filter error

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

my searchRequest like this，I only want to get two skill_group (id = 6806,6805)aggregation result ,so I add filter both in query and aggregation . but I still get other skill_group aggregation result.
the es version is 7.1

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "terms": {
                    "skill_group_id": [6806, 6805],
                    "boost": 1.0
                }
            }],
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "test": {
            "filter": {
                "terms": {
                    "skill_group_id": [6806, 6805],
                    "boost": 1.0
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "SKILLGROUP": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "skill_group_id",
                        "size": 10000,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [{
                            "_count": "desc"
                        }, {
                            "_key": "asc"
                        }],
                        "collect_mode": "breadth_first"
                    },
                    "aggregations": {
                        "WORKSTATUS": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "status",
                                "size": 10000,
                                "min_doc_count": 1,
                                "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                                "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                                "order": [{
                                    "_count": "desc"
                                }, {
                                    "_key": "asc"
                                }],
                                "collect_mode": "breadth_first"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the result is like this
[image]

Comment: Is it possible that `skill_group_id` is an array in your documents?

Comment: yes ，the skill_group_id is an array.  I did not find relevant instructions in the official documentation？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `skill_group_id` is an array, then aggregating on `skill_group_id` will aggregate on all values of that array.

What you can do in addition to the filter, is to also [leverage the `include` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_with_exact_values_2) on the `terms` aggregation, like this:

```
            "SKILLGROUP": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "skill_group_id",
                    "size": 10000,
                    "include": [6806, 6805],            <--- add this
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                    "order": [{
                        "_count": "desc"
                    }, {
                        "_key": "asc"
                    }],
                    "collect_mode": "breadth_first"
                },
```

Comment: The problem is solved。thanks